# Inside-outside algorithm in PCFG (NLP)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, nlp

My professor is asking me to study and implement the **unsupervised** inside-outside learning algorithm in PCFG (Probabilistic Context Free Grammar).

When it comes to unsupervised, my professor told the the only input are some training sentences and the number of non-terminals. What my program should learn from them is the probability for each rule (rules are generated from non-terminals, actually all possible matches format as A->BC ).

Okay now guess we have a very simple situation, we have a sentence "I love you", and the number of non-terminals is 2.

I assume the two non-terminals are A and B. these rules are generated:

```
A->AA; A->AB; A->BA; A->BB; A->I; A->love; A->you;

B->AA; B->AB; B->BA; B->BB; B->I; B->love; B->you;
```

Well the sum probability of all rules with a distinct left value is 1, here in this example, `P(A->AA) + P(A->AB) + P(A->BA) + P(A->BB) + P(A->I) + P(A->love) + p(A->you) = 1.`

**My first problem is:** should the sum of a distinct right value also be 1? For example should the statements like below true?

`P(A->AB) + P(B->AB) = 1`

`P(A->love) + P(B->love) = 1`

Well i don't need a precise mathematical derivation, but it would be so nice if you could give me an explanation to make my sense.

**My second problem is:** I want to use JavaScript to implement this algorithm, but my peers are all trying to use Java or Python. What I thought is that js is faster than python and it could be easily embed into a web application.

But I have no experience in this kind of complex algorithm, so i am not sure is it okay to use JavaScript here? and is there any advantages or disadvantages?

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: _"we have a sentence "I love you", and the number of non-terminals is 2."_ -> "I" , "love" ?

Comment: If you will use Node.js, you might get a huge performance boost over vanilla Python.

Check this article that I have found during the research on the topic:
http://www.cdotson.com/2014/08/nodejs-vs-python-vs-pypy-a-simple-performance-comparison/

After all the decision depends on your personal expirience with JS and deadlines.

Comment: @guest271314 "I", "love", "you" are terminals, non-terminals represent..ehh i see like verb or noun. here i just have 2 non-terminal to make it easy to see

Comment: @halfzebra i have no experience in java and python. i do have some js coding so i want to use js. so you mean js is okay for NLP? since all the NLP code i could got from git are in java or python... so i wonder is js not suitable for NLP?

Comment: @Summer Sun People do use Node.js for NLP algoritms, here is a good example https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first problem:**

I have confirmed with my professor, the suming of probibilities with a single left value should be one. like this: `P(A->AA) + P(A->AB) + P(A->BA) + P(A->BB) + P(A->I) + P(A->love) + p(A->you) = 1.`

But the suming of probabilities with a single right value may not be one, `P(A->AB) + P(B->AB) != 1`.

**For the second problem:**

I actually have done my summer project of nlp using node.js, and it's actually much faster than python i think.